# Error when running simple program in assembly

Tags: assembly, tasm

I wrote a simple program in assembly and I tried to run it using TASM(Turbo) and TLINK. After I run the executable I get this error:

[image: Screenshot with error]

```
TITLE 1st Program
.286
.model small

.data
val1 db 0 

.code
main PROC
    mov bl, 2Bh
    mov val1, bl
    
    mov bl, 2Ah ;I suspect this is the line that causes the problem

    mov ah, 02 ;calls interrupt to display val1
    mov dl, val1
    int 21h

    mov ah, 04Ch ;calls interrupt to terminat program
    mov al, 00
    int 21h 
main ENDP
end main
```

If I remove the line that just moves 2ah to BL, it works perfectly fine. I tried changing the value being added to BL but I still get the error message. I just want to understand what causing the error.

Thank you!

Later edit: I've managed to solve the error by adding .stack 100h. Can anyone explain what exactly happend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably there was no memory reserved for the application's stack or there was too little of it and either the `int 21h` or hardware interrupt handler caused a stack overflow and a data/code corruption that led to execution of data or corrupted code.

`mov bl, 2Ah` per se could not have caused the problem anyhow.

Comment: For simple routines I advise to push the registers on the stack before using them, and to pop them at the end of the routine.. This gives you more freedom to do with the registers whatever you want.